# Encoding 8-bit operand size? Is there a prefix for that like for 16-bit?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, machine-code, instructions, instruction-encoding

In instruction encoding Default sizes are:

```
operand size is 32 bit
address size is 64 bit
```

We can use the legacy prefix:

```
0x66 – Operand-size override prefix
```

to make operand size 16. What if I want to make it 8 bits not 16?

Comment: Please don't try to circumvent the question limit with multiple questions in one.  Users get suspended for that.

Comment: One of your classmates already got suspended a few days ago for the exact same thing, so take it seriously.  As for your question: 8 bit instructions have separate opcodes.

Comment: To learn more about this, try assembling and disassembling a lot of examples by yourself, comparing with a table such as https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding.

Comment: Just this once: `movl $1234, 64(%rax, %rbx, 4)`.  `$1234` is an immediate, `64` is a displacement, `%rax` base, `%rbx` index, `4` scale.

Comment: [Is there a default operand size in the x86-64 (AMD64) architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68289333) covers this, but it's a broader question.  Still, it came up as the 3rd  hit for my `site:stackoverflow.com x86 8-bit operand size opcode prefix` search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What if I want to make it 8 bits not 16?

You can't do this with prefixes.  Instructions that support an 8-bit operand size do so with an entirely separate opcode, not with an override prefix.

For instance:

```
   0:   01 d9                   addl    %ebx,%ecx
   2:   66 01 d9                addw    %bx,%cx
   5:   00 d9                   addb    %bl,%cl
```

The 32-bit `add` is opcode `01`, with a mod/rm byte of `d9`.  The 16-bit add is identical but with the `66` operand size prefix.  However the 8-bit add is opcode `00` instead.

The explanation for this is historical.  The 16-bit 8086 CPU supported 8-bit and 16-bit operands, and used separate opcodes for the two: `00` for `addb` and `01` for `addw`.  (This is still what you get when you run a modern chip in real mode, like in a boot sector.)  The 32-bit 80386 wanted to add 32-bit operands while still supporting both 8 and 16, but there was no room for so many more opcodes, so for 32-bit protected mode they made all the formerly 16-bit instructions act as 32-bit instead, with an override available to go back to 16 bit, and they left the 8-bit instructions alone.  (In real mode the operand size override has the opposite effect: `01` is `addw` and `66 01` is `addl`.)

Comment: Your answers are amazing, please take a look at this too :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68605218/understanding-instruction-encoding