# Understanding Instruction Encoding?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att, machine-code, instruction-encoding

I used a website to encode this:

```
movw $8, 4(%r8d,%esi,4)
```

and got:

```
encoding (hex): 67 66 41 C7 44 B0 04 08 00
```

Thanks to you I nearly understand everything except 2 small points:

1. Here we are moving 2 bytes immediate to 4 bytes address. They used C7 opcode which according to the table I have means one of the following:

- mov imm16 to r/m16
- mov imm32 to r/m32
- mov imm32 (sign extended) to r/m64

Why there is no match?

2. Why immediate is 2 bytes? according to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a match.  It's the first one "mov imm16 to r/m16", because of the `w` in the mnemonic `movw`.  `r/m16` means that 16 bits (two bytes) of memory are being read/written.  It so happens that you are using a 32-bit effective address to identify which two bytes of memory are to be written, but that's not part of the `r/m16` notation.

The immediate is two bytes because two bytes are to be written.  There would be no point in having more.  Though there are some examples, like the third case, where the immediate is shorter than the operand size and is zero- or sign-extended.

Comment: But I don't get it we are summing 32 bit addresses so we get 32 bit address... w means write to 16 bit address so which 16 bit we take lower ones or higher ones?

Comment: I think terminology like "32 bit address" is confusing you.  The address is 32 bits, but we are using to identify 16 bits worth of memory.  For instance, suppose `r8d + (esi * 4) + 4` comes out to equal `0x12345678`.  Then your `movw` instruction will write `08` to the byte at address `0x12345678`, and write `00` to the byte at address `0x12345679`. Writing two bytes = 16 bits. If you used `movb`, only the byte at `0x12345678` would be written.  If you used `movl`, the four bytes at `0x12345678..0x1234567b` would be written (with the values `08 00 00 00` respectively).

Comment: @coolmo: Literally writing with a 16-bit address would mean writing the bytes starting at `0x5678` (it would always be the low bits).  There is no encoding for this in 64-bit long mode, though there is in 32-bit protected mode (sort of, you become more limited in addressing modes).  It is pretty much useless either way.

Comment: Now it's clear, last thing there is an opcode for mov imm32 (sign extended) to r/m64 and another one for mov imm64 to r/m64 how may I know which to use (how may I know if the instruction does sign extension or not)?

Comment: @coolmo: At the level of assembly you don't really care about the sign extension: you specify the actual value you want written.  If the assembler can represent it as a sign-extended value, it will assemble it; otherwise pick a different encoding or complain.  As for `mov imm64 to r/m64`, I think you are mistaken: no such encoding exists.  There is an instruction to `mov imm64 to r64` (register only), `REX.W + B8`.  The GNU assembler will automatically pick this encoding if you specify an immediate that does not fit in 32-bits sign extended, or you can force it with the `movabsq` mnemonic.

Comment: @coolmo: For example `movq $0xfffffffffedcba98, %rax` will give you the "mov imm32 sign extended to r/m64` encoding, `REX.W + C7`.  So will `movq $0xfffffffffedcba98, (%rax, %rsi, 8)`.  However `movq $0xfedcba9876543210, %rax` will give you `REX.W + B8`, and `movq $0xfedcba9876543210, (%rax, %rsi, 8)` will fail to assemble.

Comment: @coolmo: The official x86 terminology for these concepts are "address size" vs. "operand size".  Those two attributes of an instruction are totally separate and orthogonal, and are controlled by different prefixes.

Comment: @coolmo: Unfortunately x86 doesn't have any mov-immediate that sign-extends a byte immediate (which would allow 3-byte mov to reg for small numbers),  Only x86-64's REX.W version of `mov $imm32, r/m32`.  The REX.W version of `mov $imm32, reg` (no ModRM) is special and takes a 64-bit immediate.  Re: assemblers choosing automatically: if you use an symbolic address like `mov $func, %rdi`, GAS will default to `movq`.  Only if the value is a *compile*-time (not link-time) constant can it choose movabs if needed.  [Difference between movq and movabsq in x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40315803)